# Progressive JPEG hardware encoding

Tags: video

Is it possible to get progressive JPEG hardware-accelerated encoding to work on Raspberry Pi? I.e.:

- Is it possible to use existing hardware for this purpose by fixing the drivers?
- Can anyone recommend another board [relatively cheap] onto which this task can be offloaded?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a Raspberry Pi developer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=92401), that's impossible. Case closed.

Comment: It may almost take half a second to encode a jpeg, but have you tried using the GPU for this task? Borrowing the GPU part from [this code](https://bitbucket.org/bensch128/omxjpegencode/src/ccdbef92035e9b321e3ba04ff0e044e9351efd39/jpeg_encoder.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) may speed up the encoding. In the `init` function, the input and output formats are given to the GPU. And in the `encode` function the input buffer is transformed into an output buffer. It uses `ilclient` and `OMX`.